# Access BusinessObjects via Java API?

Tags: jdbc, business-objects

Is it possible to access BusinessObjects XI via a Java API? I want to programmatically extract data from BusinessObjects in Java, much the same as I would from an Oracle database using a JDBC driver...

Comment: Yes; which version are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to keep in mind is that BusinessObjects itself does not contain any data, it merely facilitates data access through an abstraction layer (called *semantic layer* or *universe*).

Depending on the version of BusinessObjects you're using, there are different ways to extract data through BusinessObjects. Have a look at [SAP BusinessObjects BI SDK](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-8777) for a full overview of the possibilities throughout the different versions.

Just a word of warning: in BI 4 (the latest major version of BusinessObjects), several Java interfaces are deprecated in favour of a REST interface.